# I tried to import a data set from text file i got an Nameerror

Tags: python, pandas, python-import, nameerror

I just started learning pandas and when I tried to import a data set from a text file I got a Name error and both files in the same folder
this is my the code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(pokemon_data.csv)
```

and that's what I got

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/mohammed/PycharmProjects/pandastut/pokemondata.py",
>   line 3, in
>
> df = pd.read_csv(pokemon_data.csv)
>
> NameError: name 'pokemon_data' is not defined

Comment: `pd.read_csv('pokemon_data.csv')`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, it's a trivial matter of missing quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write pokemon_data.csv in quotation marks like `df = pd.read_csv("pokemon_data.csv")`.